Determine a function by symmetry
I'd like to know a form of functions (called 3-point function) that have symmetry under some transformation.
The symmetry is followings.
$G_{ijk}$ is a function over $\mathbb{C}^3$ and satisfies
$$G_{ijk}(z_1,z_2,z_3)=\prod_{l=1}^3(\dfrac{dw}{dz_l}(z_l))^{h_l}(\overline{\dfrac{dw}{dz_l}(z_l))}^{\overline{h_l}}G_{ijk}(w(z_1),w(z_2),w(z_3))\ \ \ (9.1)$$
for all transformation $w$ (I define the set of transformations below).
Each $h_l$ or $\overline{h_l}$ is a fixed real number ($\overline{h_l}$ doesn't mean complex conjugate!). Transformations are rotations$$r_\alpha:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto e^{i\alpha}z,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$ translations $$t_a :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto z+a, a\in\mathbb{C}$$
and dilatations $$d_{\tau} :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto e^{\tau}z, \tau\in\mathbb{R}$$.
$G_{ij}$ case is easily proved in a text book  (axiom 2 and axiom 4 are the symmetry I mentioned above).

In the same way, I tried to prove for $ijk$ case.
$$G_{ijk}(z_1,z_2,z_3)=G_{ijk}(z_{13},z_{23},0)=z_{23}^{-(h_1+h_2+h_3)}\overline{z_{23}}^{-(\overline{h_1}+\overline{h_2}+\overline{h_3})}G_{ijk}(\dfrac{z_{13}}{z_{23}},1,0)$$
However there is a still degree of freedom of function $G(z):=G_{ijk}(z,1,0)$. How can we restrict degree of freedom up to complex number?

What's the connection with group theory?

@Kan't If we add inversion transformation, it becomes Mobius group. Translations and rotations make Poincare group. Dilatations itself is a group.

Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837957/2451
